# How do I register a Jersey ApplicationEventListner/RequestEventListner to Dropwizard?

Tags: java, jersey, server, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I was wondering is there any chance to get the original monitoring listeners of Jersey (ApplicationEventListner and RequestEventListner) to work with Dropwizard ?

Digged in Google but found nothing good.

Thanks

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/mira/entry/monitoring_of_restful_jersey_applicaiton this may help

Comment: Thank you man, environment.jersey ().register (XyzListner.class) worked